# Jquery Calendar.setup function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now i am using this date picker action function based on input field ID,
is it possible to use based on input field Class name.Because if i create dynamic date field i want use same function based on input field class name.any one give me solution i tried lot

```
Calendar.setup({
    inputField : "jfrom_time",   //Input Field ID
    trigger: 'f_btn1',        //Button ID
    onSelect   : function() { this.hide() },
    showTime   : 12,
    dateFormat : "%d-%m-%Y"

  });
```

Comment: Calendar is Existing jquery function name

Comment: I understand. What is Calendar plugin, there are several of them. To answer you question one must know what library you ar eusing.

Comment: I think you mean this plugin http://www.dynarch.com/jscal/, is it true ?

Comment: Dynarch Calendar -- JSCal2, version 1.9,  www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar

Answer (score 0):

Based on the doc,

inputField — an ID **or reference to an  element** that the calendar will automatically update. Only for popup calendars.

I would say you can do the following:

```
var myCalInput = $('.myCalendarClass')[0];
Calendar.setup({
    inputField : myCalInput,
    trigger: 'f_btn1',        //Button ID
    onSelect   : function() { this.hide() },
    showTime   : 12,
    dateFormat : "%d-%m-%Y"

});
```

Comment: Is there a way to store the value of the date chosen? I am trying to do an onchange function on a Calendar.setup input field.